# Writeable tmpfs volume on existing directory in read-only docker container giving: Read-only file system

Tags: docker, containers

Trying to set up a mysql container in docker with the read-only flag set for security, but running into this error:

[ERROR] Could not create unix socket lock file /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock.lock.

Trying to alleviate the problem by mounting /var/run/mysqld as a tmpfs, however it seems that as long as the container is read-only the tmpfs mount is also read-only.

```
docker run --read-only --mount type=tmpfs,destination=/var/run/mysqld,tmpfs-mode=1777 mysql:5 touch /var/run/mysqld/test
touch: cannot touch '/var/run/mysqld/test': Read-only file system
```

Using a volume mount instead of tmpfs works, but that is not what I want to do:

```
docker run --read-only --mount destination=/var/run/mysqld mysql:5 touch /var/run/mysqld
```

Testing it on a non-existant directory also works:

```
docker run --read-only --mount type=tmpfs,destination=/test,tmpfs-mode=1777 mysql:5 touch /test/test
```

And it works if you remove the read-only flag from the container:

```
docker run --mount type=tmpfs,destination=/var/run/mysqld,tmpfs-mode=1777 mysql:5 touch /var/run/mysqld/test
```

**Is this by design or a bug or am I missing some setting?**

Docker version 19.03.12, build 48a66213fe